# Hibernate: hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update show generated sql

Tags: java, hibernate, hbm2ddl

I wish to pass to Hibernate's [SessionFactory](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html)

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

and see in log file generated sql statements. Is it possible w/o java coding (know how to achieve the result with [SchemaExport](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html), but hope that hibernate has "in box" solution)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could setup logging to System.out using

- `SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")`
- or log4j

  ```
  log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG, SQL_APPENDER   
  log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false
  ```

EDIT: This maybe also helpful [Hibernate sql logging with values](http://ahoehma.wordpress.com/2009/06/03/hibernate-sql-logging-with-values/)

Comment: Unfortunately, hbm2ddl ignore both options. So I don't see any alter/create statement in my log file.

Comment: @FoxyBOA for ddl statements you should try :
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=debug

Answer (score 3):

You can also set a debug breakpoint on

```
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(boolean, boolean)
```

and see how it goes.

Comment: Or `SchemaExport` if this is not an update but an initial schema creation